# Subtract two date fields in Days and return value to another fields

Tags: javascript, date, field, subtraction

I'm trying to create a javascript that will subtract two date fields (sysdate and targstartdate) and take that result set value and update another field in that same table.

Comment: What do you want to subtract them with? Do you want to subtract one with the other? In what format should the result be in (eg. number of days,  milliseconds)?

Comment: As a general tip: have a look at http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
```

**script**

```
var date1 = new Date("7/11/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/12/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
document.getElementById("text1").value=diffDays;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. Can I use the field names instead of static dates? Also, taking the result set and updating another field with that result? Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: `var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById("yourInputId").value);` that is to create the date with the content of the field, about updating a field with the answer, that's what the last line of code does. `document.getElementById("text1").value=diffDays;`

Comment: last line of the code  update the result to textfield (text1)